# SFML getting window to another class via constructor not working

Tags: c++, pointers, window, sfml

I'm trying to create an object where the SFML RenderWindow object is passed over as a parameter, but it isn't simply working, it complains all the time about pointer and that I'm using them in the wrong way.

Here you have my .h file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML\System.hpp>
#include <SFML\Window.hpp>
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>

using namespace sf;

class Shot
{
private:

    RenderWindow &mainWindow;

public:

    Shot(RenderWindow &window);
    void add(float x, float y, float velocity);

};
```

and here my .cpp

```
#include "Shot.h"

Shot::Shot(RenderWindow &window) : mainWindow(&window)
{
    mainWindow -> window;
}

void Shot::add(float x, float y, float velocity)
{
    CircleShape shape(10);

    shape.setPosition(Vector2f(x, y));

    shape.setFillColor(Color::Yellow);

    mainWindow.draw(shape);
}
```

Errors:

```
Error   1   error C2248: 'sf::NonCopyable::operator =' : cannot access private member declared in class 'sf::NonCopyable'
Error   2   error C2248: 'sf::NonCopyable::operator =' : cannot access private member declared in class 'sf::NonCopyable'
```

i honestly have no clue what's the problem by now an I've probably done it all wrong, but any help would really be appreciated! :)

Best Regards

FreeSirenety

Comment: What is the code inside Shot's constructor?

Comment: Your header and source code are the same. Bad copy past. Also, give us the actual error message. Aside from that, refrain from using `\ ` in inclusion path: that's not standard. Use `/` instead.

Comment: Now edited and thanks for noting my misstake! :)

Comment: `mainWindow -> window;` should be `*mainWindow = *window;`

Comment: It doesn't recognize the * operators

Answer (score 1):

In your .cpp file, you do:

```
Shot::Shot(RenderWindow &window) : mainWindow(&window)
{
    mainWindow -> window;
}
```

but `window` is a reference, so you simply can do:

```
Shot::Shot(RenderWindow &window) : mainWindow(window)
{}
```

Also, I wouldn't use `using namespace sf;`, it can make the code confusing after awhile.